# how do I copy a file to azure from a website via ftp in code?

Tags: azure, ftp

I have written code to download large .zip backup files from my website via FTP.
However I want to send the files to Azure without downloading locally first.

I expect that Blob Storage may be the best place to store them.

How do I automate this?

Comment: Is your website hosted on Azure as a Azure Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect that Blob Storage may be the best place to store them.

You are right, Blob Storage is the best place.

Unfortunately, Azure has no plan on add feature "upload data to Azure blobs by a classic FTP client".

So if you want to send it from your own website. There are external solutions that provide direct FTP and SFTP access to Azure Blob storage such as http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com.

Here is an official response on this feature https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/397724-allow-to-upload-data-to-azure-blobs-by-a-classic-f

Answer (score 3):

Azure Blob Storage is definitely a good place to store files. If you are looking for an easy way to automatically transfer from an FTP to a blob storage you should have a look a logic App and especially this recipe : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-logic-app-ftp-to-blob/

However there will always be some kind of download involved under the hood.